# Javascript: invalid argument in IE8 issue with variable object properties

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object

I am trying to dynamically style an element like this

```
var element = document.querySelector('.myElement');
var prop = 'left'; // this is incoming property variable computed by other code
var leftTop = ['left','top'];
var widthHeight = ['width','height'];



if (prop === 'left' || prop === 'top') {
   element.style[prop] = 20+'px'; // the condition determines that left/top property is to be used
} else {
   element.style[prop] = 40+'px'; // the condition determines that width/height property is to be used
}
```

Error is:

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. File: script.js, Line: 275, Column: 5

I know I can use `element.style.left` when condition is satisfied, and IE8 does the job, but in my case the array variables contain 20+ properties and I really need to make it work with `element.style[prop]`.

Thanks for any advice or solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put 
`var element = document.querySelector('.myElement');` into your `window.onload`. What you have right now is grabbing `.myElement` before the element exists. If you need to keep it global then just define as:

```
var element;
window.onload = function(){
    element = document.querySelector('.myElement');
    if (prop === 'left' || prop === 'top') {
        element.style[prop] = 20+'px'; // the condition determines that left/top property is to be used
    } else {
        element.style[prop] = 40+'px'; // the condition determines that width/height property is to be used
    }   
};
```

Fiddle with error: http://jsfiddle.net/a9fms3um/
Fiddle with no error: http://jsfiddle.net/a9fms3um/1/
Also be certain that the element does exist with that class on the page.

Comment: I will edit my question, I think we are missing the point. Done.

Comment: And the point is, if the element is define then it should work no problem. Does this error for you as well? http://jsfiddle.net/a9fms3um/3/

Comment: Please check my updated question, it's not about scope or events, it's really about `element.style[prop]`.

Comment: Which argument is throwing it, meaning for what value of `prop` is the issue? As it stands your code should work no problems. Have you stepped through your code with the debugger and inspected the element and the prop you are attempting? (you can use the statement `debugger;` to kick it off).  Or even add some checks to your code such as `if(element && element.style && element.style[prop])`?